# Is there a way to disassemble the current running file?

Tags: python-3.x, disassembly

So we all know it's possible to disassemble a function using
`dis.dis(f)`
but the problem I am having is figuring out how to disassemble a whole module aka the main "function". We can get the current module using `sys.modules[__name__]`. But trying to disassemble this results in a list of all functions in the file being decompiled. Not the actual main "function". For example you have this code:

```
import time, dis, sys

while True:
    print(dis.dis(sys.modules[__name__]))
    time.sleep(5)
```

When you run this it just prints None, as there are no functions available. Is it possible to either disassemble the main "function", or to get the bytecode so we can disassemble it later?

The reason I want this is to "dump" the original bytecode from a file protected by https://github.com/dashingsoft/pyarmor. I am aware that pyarmor modifies the bytecode but the disassembly of it still should give quite a good insight of the code.

Comment: What do you consider the 'main "function"' to be? "or to get the bytecode so we can disassemble it later" since you know how to disassemble a function, why try and specifically get just its bytecode?

Comment: I used the word function between quotes because I mean the main module. So the main script basically. Sorry if I worded it wrong.

Comment: Are you looking for ``dis.dis(sys.modules["__main__"])`` perhaps? That would literally disassemble the main module. (Note that ``dis.dis`` already writes to stdout, by the way.)

Comment: That wouldn't disassemble the main module. It would disassemble all functions in the main module. I showed this in my example where I had no functions and so it printed None

Comment: "For a module, it disassembles all functions" - https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#dis.dis

Comment: Well, as you already found out disassembling a module is equivalent to disassembling its functions, so I'm not sure what else you expect.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242039/discussion-between-svenskithesource-and-mistermiyagi).